# Enqueue ActiveJob task with destroyed object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

In controller's action, I destroy a record and then pass it as an argument to ActiveJob.

```
def destroy
  post = Post.find params[:id]
  post.destroy
  CleanUpJob.perform_later post
end
```

And in my job's perform, I need to do some cleanup actions with that destroyed record.

```
def perform(post)
  log_destroyed_content post.id, post.title
end
```

When I call it as delayed with .perform_later - it does not execute at all. But when I change to .perform_now - it works as expected. This Job needs to deal with both destroyed and persisted records.

I'm using lates Rails, development env with default async activejob adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `.perform_later` with an `ActiveRecord` object, `ActiveJob` will try to serialize it into a [global id](https://github.com/rails/globalid)

You are deleting your record from the database, which means your job won't find it when it runs.

You could pass a hash with all the attributes:
`CleanUpJob.perform_later(post.attributes)`

Alternatively, you could flag your model for deletion and call destroy in the job when you are actually done with the record. Think of it as soft-deleting the record first:

```rb
# in the controller
def destroy
  post = Post.find params[:id]
  post.update(state: :archived) # or whatever makes more sense for your application
  CleanUpJob.perform_later(post.id, post.title)
end

# in the job
def perform(post_id, post_title)
  log_destroyed_content(post_id, post_title)
  post.destroy
end
```

You will want to make sure to exclude 'soft-deleted' records from your user-facing queries.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the destroyed `post` just pass its `id` and `title`.

```
# in the controller
def destroy
  post = Post.find params[:id]
  post.destroy
  CleanUpJob.perform_later(post.id, post.title)
end

# in the job
def perform(post_id, post_title)
  log_destroyed_content(post_id, post_title)
end
```